# How to generate a new image from overlaid text and images over one large background image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, aws-lambda

I've got an image on the page (I'll call it the background image) and I've allowed the user to enter some text that is positioned via css over the background image. As well, there are a few other small images that will be automatically position over the background image using css based on the text.

I want to turn what the user setup/created into an actual downloadable image now, essentially "flattening the layers" in photo editing terms.

I'd also ideally like to do this at a very high resolution as the original background image exists in a much larger and higher resolution format than the one the people see when editing.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. I'd be using NodeJS and Lambdas.

One solution I think would be to perhaps have another page exist with the full size background image and have the css reposition and resize everything perfectly and take a screenshot with puppeteer or something, although I don't know if that'll lose the quality of the original image somehow?

Or do I size the overlayed text and images correctly for the background and take screenshots of each of them, somehow add transparency, and then somehow merge the pictures?

Is there a way easier thing I'm missing or some package that can help?

Comment: Have you thought of having an element (rather than another page), off screen, with the full size image and other stuff (suitably enlarged) and using something like html2canvas on the element?

Comment: Actually, since you have full control of what you want in the final image you maybe could just write it all to a canvas yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an element which has the full-size image, overlay the users' text and any other required image - both suitably scaled up in size and position, you can save that element on a canvas and then convert that to an image.

Here is some code to give the idea. It's using html2canvas but actually you could just create the canvas and draw the images and write the text to it without needing a library if preferred. (The code runs from my server and on my laptop and on https://codepen.io/rgspaces/pen/RwoNxVQ  but does not run in a SO snippet - ??a CORS problem with iframe inside snippet system??).

```
<head>
<script src="https://ahweb.org.uk/html2canvas.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --t: 20px; /*  distance from top of the user's text in the workspace */
  --l: 20px; /* distance from left of the user's text */
  --f: 30px; /* fontsize of the user's text in the workspace */
}

#big {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100vw;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#workspace {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
}

#workspace .mainimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#workspace .text, #big .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

#workspace .text {
  top: var(--t);
  left: var(--l);
  font-size: var(--f);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="big">
    <img id="bigimg" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563.jpg" class="mainimg" crossOrigin = "anonymous">
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="workspace">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563.jpg" class="mainimg">
    <div class="text">User's text</div>
    <!-- other imgs -->
  </div>
  <p>YOUR IMAGE WILL APPEAR BELOW - RIGHT CLICK TO SAVE IT TO FILE (WINDOWS); PRESS TO SAVE TO PHOTOS (IOS)</p>
  <img id="resultimg" style="clear:both;" src=""/>

<script>
function start() {
  let big = document.getElementById('big');
  let bigImg = document.getElementById('bigimg');
  let bigText = document.querySelector('#big .text');
  let width = bigimg.width;
  let height = bigimg.height;
  let workspace = document.getElementById('workspace');
  let workspaceText = document.querySelector('#workspace .text');
  let props = window.getComputedStyle(workspace, null);
  let scaling = width/props.getPropertyValue("width").replace('px','');

  bigText.innerHTML = workspaceText.innerHTML;
  // just some simple scaling to give an idea for now
  bigText.style.fontSize = 'calc(var(--f) * ' + scaling + ')';
  bigText.style.top = 'calc(var(--t) * ' + scaling + ')';
  bigText.style.left = 'calc(var(--l) * ' + scaling + ')';
  big.style.display = 'inline-block';
  
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  html2canvas(big, {allowTaint: true, useCORS: true, logging: true, width: width, height: height})
    .then((canvas) => {
      big.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
      const resultImg = document.getElementById('resultimg')
      resultImg.src = imgData;
      resultImg.style.width = width + 'px';
      resultImg.style.height = 'auto';    
    });
  }
  
window.onload = start;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```